# git remote add origin https://... is not helping

Tags: git

This issue is similar to other issues at Stackoverflow, but the thing is that the help is not working for me:

This is the initial error:

```
fatal: remote error:
  You can't push to git://github.com/...
  Use https://github.com/...
```

I did (this is the help at Stackoverflow which doesn't work for me):

```
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/my_user_name/my_repo.git
```

and then:

```
git push origin master
```

tried:

```
rm -rf .git
```

and started all new.

No help.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Clear your git remote and then add ssh or https remote.
Check remote link.
Check your ssh key.
etc.

`git remote rm origin
git remote add origin git@github.com:user/repo.git
git push origin master`

Answer (score 0):

```
git init
git remote add origin https://github.com/my_user_name/my_repo.git
```

At this point, below command should show the remote added successfully.

```
git remote -v
```

Then try a push:

```
git push -u origin master
```

The -u flag will link your local branch with remote branch, so that later you can just do `git pull`.

Edit: Also make sure you use a valid URL for creating the origin - either the SSH or the HTTPS one which you can copy from the github page's top right link. It will be `git@github.com:xxx/<project_name>.git` (for SSH) or `https://github.com/xxx/<project_name>.git` (HTTPS).
`git://` protocol is not supported by github.

Comment: When I do the second command, this I get: `origin git://github.com/... (fetch)
origin git://github.com/... (push)`